# Quickest way to upgrade Ubuntu Hardy Heron to latest version

Tags: ubuntu

I just got a netbook (Dell Vostro A90N) with Hardy Heron on it and I'd like to upgrade it to the latest version of Ubuntu. Whats the quickest way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way to upgrade is to update /etc/apt/sources.list as others have suggested. However, *the approved way* is to [upgrade to Intrepid first](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IntrepidUpgrades), then [to Jaunty](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading), following the [instructions provided](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes/904#Upgrading).

> Users of Ubuntu 8.10 can upgrade to
>   Ubuntu 9.04 by a convenient automated
>   process. Users of older Ubuntu
>   releases need to upgrade to Ubuntu
>   8.10 first, and then to 9.04. Complete instructions may be found at
>   http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading.

This should reduce the likelihood of having to troubleshoot issues arising from the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to Jaunty Jackalope rather than Hardy Heron and then run:

```
apt-get update ; apt-get dist-upgrade
```

There are GUI ways of doing that too, but I've been using command line tools for years and have never seen any reason to change.

Comment: What parts of the sources.list file need to be changed? It looks to have Dell-specific URLs right now.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, Im a total linux n00b

Comment: nagul's answer has a good link describing the upgrade process.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace "hardy" with "jaunty" and do:

```
apt-get update ; apt-get dist-upgrade -u
```