# How to get my Apple Keyboard to work on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, keyboard

I'm trying to use a USB keyboard with my Ubuntu laptop, but when I plug in the keyboard, it is not even detected. I am trying to use the [Apple Slim Aluminum Keyboard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB869LL/A?fnode=MTY1NDA1Mg&mco=MTA4NDU5OTE). It would also be nice if the USB ports on the keyboard could work, but I can get by without that luxury.

How can I get my Apple Slim Aluminum Keyboard to work with Ubuntu?

**Update:** After upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu (9.04 Jaunty), the keyboard was detected and types just fine. There are a few quirks like the clear button being used as the numlock key but that seems to be well documented on other sites.

Comment: Could you provide the output from dmesg when you connect & disconnect the keyboard?

Comment: also - what version of ubuntu are you using?  There are some known bugs with this keyboard in 8.04

Comment: DaveParillo is right. Open a console, plug in your keyboard and type <code>dmesg | tail -20</code>, then please paste the output here.

Comment: Well, you obviously don't need the <code> tags, so just type the following:
dmesg | tail -20

Comment: It is also helpful to run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal, and then plug in your keyboard and watch what happens. (This will echo all the system log messages to your terminal.) Also, compare the output of `lsusb` ("list usb devices") before and after plugging in your device.

Comment: Just so you know, even 9.04 isn't the newest version. Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala has been released! :-)

Comment: I know 9.04 isn't the newest. That's why I said "a newer version" instead of "the newest"

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems with Ubuntu recognizing my Apple slim aluminum keyboard until I upgraded [from 8.04 to a newer version of Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/28067/quickest-way-to-upgrade-ubuntu-hardy-heron-to-latest-version).

I would recommend upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu before hacking around trying to get the keyboard to work under 8.04. The problem might already be fixed in a newer version. Worked fine for me after upgrading to 9.04.

You may need to [fix some other quirks.](http://alandoyle.com/2009/04/30/slim-aluminum-apple-keyboard-under-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [InstallUSBKeyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallUSBKeyboard).